# EXEC Select Statement With Dynamic Column stores value into a Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have an issue with a my SQL query. I need to execute a SQL statement using `EXEC` and one of the columns is already represented with a variable and I must now put the represent the value of that column with another variable. Can this be achieved and if so, can you please suggest any other solution for this?

I found this snippet via Google. But even this doesn't give me the desired output.

My SQL Statement:

```
declare @i int, @j int =10
exec sp_executesql N'select @i ='+ @j, N'@i int output', @i output
select @i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in my Sql Server 2005:

```
    declare @i int, @j int
    set @j =10
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    set @sql = 'select @i =' + str(@j)
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@i int output', @i output
    select @i
```

Comment: thnx it works.. can i know what is that difference? oh.. other than the casting problem..

Comment: Casting, then you cannot initialize variable at the declaration, and sp_execute_sql does not accept expression as parameter. You have to send a variable, @sql in this case.

Comment: SQL server 2008 and above can initialize variables in their declarations.